# Capture the AttachmentCotextMenuDisplay event (Outlook 2013)

Tags: c#, outlook

I've been capturing attachment context menu for Outlook 2010 using following event which works wonderfully.

```
_application.AttachmentContextMenuDisplay +=new Outlook.ApplicationEvents_11_AttachmentContextMenuDisplayEventHandler(_application_AttachmentContextMenuDisplay);
```

But, when trying to capture the context menu for Outlook 2013 using the same way does not work as expected.

I also tried re purposing the context menu in XML as following which throws the error "Specified control type is incompatible with actual control type "context menu" per each line.

Is there a reliable way which I can capture this event in Outlook 2013 ?

```
<contextMenus>
<contextMenu idMso="ContextMenuAttachments">       
  <button idMso="ContextMenuAttachments" onAction="test"/>
  <toggleButton idMso="ContextMenuAttachments" onAction="test"/>
  <dynamicMenu idMso="ContextMenuAttachments" getContent="test"/>      
</contextMenu></contextMenus>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> for Outlook 2013 using the same way does not work as expected.

What code exactly did you use? Could you please be more specific? What do you mean "doesn't work"?

Anyway, to repurpose Ribbon controls you need to use the command tag. See [Temporarily Repurpose Commands on the Office Fluent Ribbon](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb462633%28v=office.12%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) for more information.

The [Office 2013 Help Files: Office Fluent User Interface Control Identifiers](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36798) list contains all available control IDs.

Comment: I used `_application.AttachmentContextMenuDisplay +=new Outlook.ApplicationEvents_11_AttachmentContextMenuDisplayEventHandler(_application_AttachmentContextMenuDisplay);` to capture when a context menu for an attachment is opened in Outlook 2010. But this event does not fire in Outlook 2013 when attachment context menu is  opened. My requirement is to capture when the context menu of an attachment is being displayed.

Comment: The [AttachmentContextMenuDisplay](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.applicationevents_11_event.attachmentcontextmenudisplay.aspx) event is deprecated.

Comment: Is there an alternative solutions for this ?

Comment: I believe you can repurpose controls on the menu. Take a look at the article I mentioned in the post.

Comment: I re purposed the "Copy" control in the context menu. My intention is to get the attachment details of the copied item via the context menu. Repurposing returns the `IRibbonControl` and a `boolean` value. Is it possible  to get the attachment details from the `IRibbonControl` ?